# Don't rotate nodes in radial tree layout in d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, charts, hierarchy

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GFe96/17/)

I can't figure out how to tweak the `transform:rotate` attribute for the nodes so that the pictures and text in the foreign objects don't rotate/ go upside down. I have tried tweaking with this block of code:

```
var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
});
```

In the Chrome Console, I change a node from

```
 <g transform="translate(226.5247584249853,-164.57987064189248)rotate(-36)">    
 <foreignObject.....></foreignObject></g>
```

to
`transform="translate(226.5247584249853,-164.57987064189248)rotate(0)`

and it works. But changing rotate to `0` in the code above would make every children node go to the left side., like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GFe96/18/)

Full code:

```
treeData = myJSON;

// Calculate total nodes, max label length
var totalNodes = 0;
var maxLabelLength = 0;
// variables for drag/drop
var selectedNode = null;
var draggingNode = null;
// panning variables
var panSpeed = 200;
var panBoundary = 20; // Within 20px from edges will pan when dragging.
// Misc. variables
var i = 0;
var duration = 750;
var root;

// size of the diagram
var width = $(document).width();
var height = $(document).height();

var diameter = 800;

var tree = d3.layout.tree().size([360, diameter / 2 - 120])
    .separation(function (a, b) {
    return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 10) / a.depth;
});

// define a d3 diagonal projection for use by the node paths later on.
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal.radial()
    .projection(function (d) {
    return [d.y, d.x / 180 * Math.PI];
});

// Define the root
root = treeData;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

// A recursive helper function for performing some setup by walking through all nodes

function visit(parent, visitFn, childrenFn) {
    if (!parent) return;
    visitFn(parent);
    var children = childrenFn(parent);
    if (children) {
        var count = children.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            visit(children[i], visitFn, childrenFn);
        }
    }
}

// Call visit function to establish maxLabelLength
visit(treeData, function (d) {
    totalNodes++;
    maxLabelLength = Math.max(d.name.length, maxLabelLength);
}, function (d) {
    return d.children && d.children.length > 0 ? d.children : null;
});


// sort the tree according to the node names
function sortTree() {
    tree.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.name.toLowerCase() < a.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;
    });
}

// Sort the tree initially incase the JSON isn't in a sorted order.
sortTree();

// TODO: Pan function, can be better implemented.

function pan(domNode, direction) {
    var speed = panSpeed;
    if (panTimer) {
        clearTimeout(panTimer);
        translateCoords = d3.transform(svgGroup.attr("transform"));
        if (direction == 'left' || direction == 'right') {
            translateX = direction == 'left' ? translateCoords.translate[0] + speed : translateCoords.translate[0] - speed;
            translateY = translateCoords.translate[1];
        } else if (direction == 'up' || direction == 'down') {
            translateX = translateCoords.translate[0];
            translateY = direction == 'up' ? translateCoords.translate[1] + speed : translateCoords.translate[1] - speed;
        }
        scaleX = translateCoords.scale[0];
        scaleY = translateCoords.scale[1];
        scale = zoomListener.scale();
        svgGroup.transition().attr("transform", "translate(" + translateX + "," + translateY + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
        d3.select(domNode).select('g.node').attr("transform", "translate(" + translateX + "," + translateY + ")");
        zoomListener.scale(zoomListener.scale());
        zoomListener.translate([translateX, translateY]);
        panTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            pan(domNode, speed, direction);
        }, 50);
    }
}

// Define the zoom function for the zoomable tree
function zoom() {
    svgGroup.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

// define the zoomListener which calls the zoom function on the "zoom" event constrained within the scaleExtents
var zoomListener = d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 1]).on("zoom", zoom);

function initiateDrag(d, domNode) {
    draggingNode = d;
    d3.select(domNode).select('.ghostCircle').attr('pointer-events', 'none');
    d3.selectAll('.ghostCircle').attr('class', 'ghostCircle show');
    d3.select(domNode).attr('class', 'node activeDrag');

    svgGroup.selectAll("g.node").sort(function (a, b) { // select the parent and sort the path's
        if (a.id != draggingNode.id) return 1; // a is not the hovered element, send "a" to the back
        else return -1; // a is the hovered element, bring "a" to the front
    });
    // if nodes has children, remove the links and nodes
    if (nodes.length > 1) {
        // remove link paths
        links = tree.links(nodes);
        nodePaths = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
            .data(links, function (d) {
            return d.target.id;
        }).remove();
        // remove child nodes
        nodesExit = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(nodes, function (d) {
            return d.id;
        }).filter(function (d, i) {
            if (d.id == draggingNode.id) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }).remove();
    }

    // remove parent link
    parentLink = tree.links(tree.nodes(draggingNode.parent));
    svgGroup.selectAll('path.link').filter(function (d, i) {
        if (d.target.id == draggingNode.id) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }).remove();

    dragStarted = null;
}

// define the baseSvg, attaching a class for styling and the zoomListener
var baseSvg = d3.select("#tree-container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .call(zoomListener);

// Define the drag listeners for drag/drop behaviour of nodes.
dragListener = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("dragstart", function (d) {
    if (d == root) {
        return;
    }
    dragStarted = true;
    nodes = tree.nodes(d);
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    // it's important that we suppress the mouseover event on the node being dragged. Otherwise it will absorb the mouseover event and the underlying node will not detect it d3.select(this).attr('pointer-events', 'none');
})
    .on("drag", function (d) {
    if (d == root) {
        return;
    }
    if (dragStarted) {
        domNode = this;
        initiateDrag(d, domNode);
    }

    // get coords of mouseEvent relative to svg container to allow for panning
    relCoords = d3.mouse($('svg').get(0));
    if (relCoords[0] < panBoundary) {
        panTimer = true;
        pan(this, 'left');
    } else if (relCoords[0] > ($('svg').width() - panBoundary)) {

        panTimer = true;
        pan(this, 'right');
    } else if (relCoords[1] < panBoundary) {
        panTimer = true;
        pan(this, 'up');
    } else if (relCoords[1] > ($('svg').height() - panBoundary)) {
        panTimer = true;
        pan(this, 'down');
    } else {
        try {
            clearTimeout(panTimer);
        } catch (e) {

        }
    }

    d.x0 = d3.event.x;
    d.y0 = d3.event.y;
    var node = d3.select(this);
    node.attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x0 + "," + (d.y0) + ")");
    updateTempConnector();
})
    .on("dragend", function (d) {
    if (d == root) {
        return;
    }
    domNode = this;
    if (selectedNode) {
        // now remove the element from the parent, and insert it into the new elements children
        var index = draggingNode.parent.children.indexOf(draggingNode);
        if (index > -1) {
            draggingNode.parent.children.splice(index, 1);
        }
        if (typeof selectedNode.children !== 'undefined' || typeof selectedNode._children !== 'undefined') {
            if (typeof selectedNode.children !== 'undefined') {
                selectedNode.children.push(draggingNode);
            } else {
                selectedNode._children.push(draggingNode);
            }
        } else {
            selectedNode.children = [];
            selectedNode.children.push(draggingNode);
        }
        // Make sure that the node being added to is expanded so user can see added node is correctly moved
        expand(selectedNode);
        sortTree();
        endDrag();
    } else {
        endDrag();
    }
});

function endDrag() {
    selectedNode = null;
    d3.selectAll('.ghostCircle').attr('class', 'ghostCircle');
    d3.select(domNode).attr('class', 'node');
    // now restore the mouseover event or we won't be able to drag a 2nd time
    d3.select(domNode).select('.ghostCircle').attr('pointer-events', '');
    updateTempConnector();
    if (draggingNode !== null) {
        update(root);
        //centerNode(draggingNode);
        draggingNode = null;
    }
}

// Helper functions for collapsing and expanding nodes.
function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d._children.forEach(collapse);
        d.children = null;
    }
}

function expand(d) {
    if (d._children) {
        d.children = d._children;
        d.children.forEach(expand);
        d._children = null;
    }
}

var overCircle = function (d) {
    console.log(d);
    selectedNode = d;
    updateTempConnector();
};
var outCircle = function (d) {
    selectedNode = null;
    updateTempConnector();
};

// Function to update the temporary connector indicating dragging affiliation
var updateTempConnector = function () {
    var data = [];
    if (draggingNode !== null && selectedNode !== null) {
        // have to flip the source coordinates since we did this for the existing connectors on the original tree
        data = [{
            source: {
                x: $('svg g').first().offset().left + selectedNode.position.left,
                y: selectedNode.position.top
            },
            target: {
                x: draggingNode.x0,
                y: draggingNode.y0
            }
        }];
    }
    var link = svgGroup.selectAll(".templink").data(data);
    link.enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "templink")
        .attr("d", d3.svg.diagonal.radial())
        .attr('pointer-events', 'none');

    link.attr("d", d3.svg.diagonal.radial());

    link.exit().remove();
};

// Function to center node when clicked/dropped so node doesn't get lost when collapsing/moving with large amount of children.
function centerNode(source) {
    scale = zoomListener.scale();
    x = -source.x0;
    y = -source.y0;
    x = x * scale + width / 2;
    y = y * scale + height / 2;
    d3.select('g').transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
    zoomListener.scale(scale);
    zoomListener.translate([x, y]);
}

// Toggle children function
function toggleChildren(d) {
    if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
    } else if (d._children) {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
    }
    return d;
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // click suppressed
    d = toggleChildren(d);
    update(d);
    //centerNode(d);
    //dofocus([{ name : 'o_id' , value : d.o_id }]);
}

function update(source) {
    // Compute the new height, function counts total children of root node and sets tree height accordingly.
    // This prevents the layout looking squashed when new nodes are made visible or looking sparse when nodes are removed
    // This makes the layout more consistent.

    var levelWidth = [1];
    var childCount = function (level, n) {
        if (n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
            if (levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);

            levelWidth[level + 1] += n.children.length;
            n.children.forEach(function (d) {
                childCount(level + 1, d);
            });
        }
    };
    childCount(0, root);
    //var newHeight = d3.max(levelWidth) * 25; // 25 pixels per line  
    // tree = tree.size([newHeight, width]);

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root); //.reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Set widths between levels based on maxLabelLength.
    //        nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    //            d.y = (d.depth * (maxLabelLength * 10)); //maxLabelLength * 10px
    //            // alternatively to keep a fixed scale one can set a fixed depth per level
    //            // Normalize for fixed-depth by commenting out below line
    //            // d.y = (d.depth * 500); //500px per level.
    //        });

    // Update the nodes…
    node = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function (d) {
        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .call(dragListener)
        .attr("class", "node")
    //            .attr("transform", function(d) {
    //                return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
    //            })
    .on('click', click)

      nodeEnter.append("foreignObject")
        .attr("class", "smallcircle")
        .attr("width", function (d) {
        var f = document.createElement("span");
        f.id = "hiddenText";
        f.style.display = 'hidden';
        f.style.padding = '0px';
        f.innerHTML = d.name;
        document.body.appendChild(f);
        textWidth = f.offsetWidth;
        var f1 = document.getElementById('hiddenText');
        f1.parentNode.removeChild(f1);
          return textWidth + 50;
        })
        .attr("overflow", "visible")
        .attr("height", 50)
        .attr("y", - 50 / 2)
        .attr("x", - 50)
        .append("xhtml:div").attr("class", "mainDiv")
        .html(function (d) {
        var htmlString = "";
            htmlString += "<div class='userImage' style='border-color:red '><img src='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6d2db975d856b8799a6198bab4777aed?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG' width='50' height='50'></div>";
            htmlString += "<div class='content' style='color:red;'>" + d.name + "</div>";
            htmlString += "<div style='clear:both;'></div>";
          return htmlString;
        })

    nodeEnter.append("text")

    .text(function (d) {
        return d.name;
    })
        .style("font", "8px serif")
        .style("opacity", 0.9)
        .style("fill-opacity", 0);

    // phantom node to give us mouseover in a radius around it
    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr('class', 'ghostCircle')
        .attr("r", 30)
        .attr("opacity", 0.2) // change this to zero to hide the target area
    .style("fill", "red")
        .attr('pointer-events', 'mouseover')
        .on("mouseover", function (node) {
        node.position = $(this).position();
        node.offset = $(this).offset();
        overCircle(node);
    })
        .on("mouseout", function (node) {
        outCircle(node);
    });

    // Update the text to reflect whether node has children or not.
    //        node.select('text')
    //            .attr("x", function(d) {
    //                return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
    //            })
    //            .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
    //                return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    //            })
    //            .text(function(d) {
    //                return d.name;
    //            });

    // Change the circle fill depending on whether it has children and is collapsed
    node.select("circle.nodeCircle")
        .attr("r", 4.5)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });


    var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
    });

    nodeUpdate.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5)
        .style("fill", function (d) {
        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

    // Fade the text in
    //        nodeUpdate.select("text")
    //            .style("fill-opacity", 1);
    nodeUpdate.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 1)
    // .attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(0)" : "rotate(180)translate(-" + (d.name.length + 50)  + ")"; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
        return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end";
    })
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return d.x < 180 ? "translate(8)" : "rotate(180)translate(-8)";
    });



    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
    })
        .remove();

    nodeExit.select("circle")
        .attr("r", 0);

    nodeExit.select("text")
        .style("fill-opacity", 0);

    // Update the links…
    var link = svgGroup.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function (d) {
        return d.target.id;
    });

    // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function (d) {
        var o = {
            x: source.x0,
            y: source.y0
        };
        return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
        });
    });

    // Transition links to their new position.
    link.transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", diagonal);

    // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
    link.exit().transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .attr("d", function (d) {
        var o = {
            x: source.x,
            y: source.y
        };
        return diagonal({
            source: o,
            target: o
        });
    })
        .remove();

    // Stash the old positions for transition.
    nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        d.x0 = d.x;
        d.y0 = d.y;
    });
}



// Append a group which holds all nodes and which the zoom Listener can act upon.
var svgGroup = baseSvg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

// Collapse all children of roots children before rendering.
root.children.forEach(function (child) {
    collapse(child);
});

// Layout the tree initially and center on the root node.
update(root);
d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", width);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rotation is set in line 1221 of your fiddle:

```
return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
```

The rotation here is required for the positioning, as you're rotating around the origin of the non-translated coordinate system. So simply removing the `rotate(...)` won't work. However, you can rotate the elements back after positioning:

```
return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")rotate(" + (-d.x + 90) + ")";
```

Complete fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GFe96/19/).

Comment: And on a general note this would have been much easier with a minimal (and not more than 1300 LOC) example.